# How to Prevent the Actual UI Content from Appearing in a Screenshot?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, screenshot

I need to do the operation here is to restrict the actual ui with some other ui when user attempts to take the screen shot, but here when i try to take the screen shot the red blocker view appears but the saved image has the actual ui content how to overcome this.

Could any one help me to getting this possible, like might you seen any of the payment or security applications with does't allows to take the screen shot but here it needs to be allowed but we need to override the actual ui presents in the partucular view.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var greetLabel: UILabel!
    
    private let navigator: HomeNavigator
    
    init(navigator: HomeNavigator) {
        self.navigator = navigator
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        setupTabBar()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavigationBar()
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleScreenshot), name: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification, object: nil)
      }
      
      override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
          NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification, object: nil)
      }
      
   
    @objc func handleScreenshot() {
        let blockerView = ScreenshotBlockerView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) {
            keyWindow.addSubview(blockerView)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.removeScreenshotBlockerView()
        }
    }
    
    
    func removeScreenshotBlockerView() {
        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) {
            for subview in keyWindow.subviews {
                if subview is ScreenshotBlockerView {
                    subview.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setupNavigationBar() {
        navigationItem.title = "Home"
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "",style: .plain,target: nil,action: nil)
    }
    
    private func setupTabBar() {
        let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(systemName: "house") , tag: 0)
        tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor =  UIColor.blue
        self.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let greetLabel = UILabel()
        greetLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        greetLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18 , weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
        greetLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        greetLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        greetLabel.text = AppConstants.shared.greetLabelText(forType: .itemConstant)
        
        self.greetLabel = greetLabel
        
        view.addSubview(greetLabel)
        
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.greetLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            self.greetLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

class ScreenshotBlockerView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are putting up the blocking view *after the screenshot is taken* - user*did*takeScreenshot. There is no notification that tells you before the screenshot is taken

Comment: That's ok @Paulw11 some of the internet banking application has the feature that i'm asking after the screen shot is taken the saved image does't have the actual ui it looks some what like the **Action Denied** in the image itself, is there any way to do that.

Comment: Lots of other possibilities in [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+prevent+screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible currently. There is just no way to receive an event, before the actual screenshot happens which we can react to. There is just an event after the screenshot is taken.

https://screenshieldkit.com/
I read that this company got a working solution, but it requires payment. They have a custom UI component to hide a view when a screenshot is taken. They do it by somehow converting the view to video with DRM

Comment: Thank you for the response!, i'll check.